# Google Sign In crashes Flutter app on launch

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have a flutter app which is using Firebase Authentication and Google Sign In.  The app was working fine before I prepared it for an initial test release to try it outside of debug mode.  Since then, when trying to run in Android Studio in debug, the app crashes immediately when it launches.

Flutter doctor shows this:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G66, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I've seen a few answers to try and align SHA keys from google play console and firebase as well as changing package versions, but I haven't found any combinations that work.

The Run console just shows:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
```

I also get this in the log:

```
2019-08-22 21:44:28.640 16297-16297/com.test.perklapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.perklapp, PID: 16297
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/auth/internal/InternalAuthProvider;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:78)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:71)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:411)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:306)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:273)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:257)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1920)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1895)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6440)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5987)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5902)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.auth.internal.InternalAuthProvider
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:78) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:71) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:411) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:306) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:273) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:257) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1920) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1895) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5987) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5902) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:78) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:71) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:411) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:306) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:273) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:257) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1920) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1895) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5987) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5902) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.perklapp-8iwPo_650CpCeJcSMtZqoQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.perklapp-8iwPo_650CpCeJcSMtZqoQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.test.perklapp-8iwPo_650CpCeJcSMtZqoQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Has anyone else faced anything like this?  I've been butting heads for a couple weeks trying to get my app back, since it was working fine before, but nothing has worked so far.  Would love any help!

Comment: have you filled in the consent screen from gcp for OAuth

Comment: @Ggriffo Where is this consent screen for OAuth? In Google Play Console? I'm not able to find it.

Comment: It's under APIs&services Oauth consent screen .follow instructions

Comment: @Ggriffo I've only got "Licensing & in-app billing", "Google Play game services", "App Indexing from Google Search", and "Real-time developer notifications" on the Services & APIs page for the app. I don't see any OAuth references

Comment: Https://console.cloud.google.com ->navigation menu -> API ..

Comment: @Ggriffo this app isn't on Google Cloud Platform, its just on Google Play Console.  When I click your link and look for this app in the drop list of instances there isn't one.  This was working fine before building a release to test on Play Store, now it just crashes.